# Address-book jQuery support

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a address book with groups and contacts, and I'd like to have some sort of jQuery functionality that allows each contact or group to be individually selected, i.e. with a checkbox

Is there a easy way to get the following functionality? (in a jQuery plugin or just plain javascript)

- Select a whole group of contacts
- Select all groups, which in order selects all contacts

SMSCity.com has this functionality that I want (see screenshot below)
[image: SMSCity.com functionality on the subject]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add a css class to each row containing the group name: e.g. `group group-friends` and then select them by calling

```
$(".group-" + groupname + " input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

and to select all contacts, just call:

```
$(".addressbook tr input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

or only those which are in a group:

```
$(".group input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```